# How to apply all geometric transformations given by modifier but without modifier itself?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface, bisect

I now watching tutorial on the low poly airplane creation from PolygonRunway: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FkaVtOkLJoI

I stuck with creating the stone. He firstly created the cube on `15:13`, then applied modifier with `CTRL + 1` then ... IDK what happened and what he actually pressed but it looks like transform applied to cube "natively" and modifier just disappeared.

Looks like he pressed `CTRL + A` but when I press it, nothing happens.

How do I repeat this? Because of without this trick I can't cut it with `Bisect` tool as he shows on `15:17`. I got some uneven ugly surface instead of straight cut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to play that section back slowed down.  What he has actually done:

- Added a subdivision surface modifier (Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>1</kbd>)
- Applied it (Shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd>)

but what is hard to see is that he has moved the mouse from the 3D viewport to the Modifiers panel, where the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd> shortcut causes the modifier to be applied.

You can accomplish the same thing by clicking the down arrow on the modifier and selecting "Apply" from the menu:

[image]

Comment: What a weird feature of blender. I would never have idea. Thanks!

Comment: @Axel all of Blender's shortcuts are sensitive to what window the mouse is over when you type them.  This is common in many programs that have multiple windows/areas and huge sets of shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> is Apply, but your Mouse have to be on top of the modifier panel not on the 3d Viewport

Comment: You'll also see a blue outline round the modifier settings to show which modifier is selected.